# String to MDX code

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following scenario:

I have my `MDX` code in a cell in a dimension.

e.g. `[MDXCode].[Code].[Code]` contains the string:

```
"([GL Account].[GL Account Code L1].&[ABC],[Measures].[Amount]) + ([GL Account].[GL Account Code L1].&[XYZ],[Measures].[Amount])"
```

Now I want this cell evaluated as `MDX` code.

I tried with `StrToMember` and `ToTuple` but do not get it working.
e.g.

```
StrToTuple([MDXCode].[Code].[Code])
```

However if I limit my example to ([GL Account].[GL Account Code L1].&[ABC],[Measures].[Amount]) it works. If I add another tuple to sum both it does not..

Comment: "I want this cell evaluated as MDX code" ...where is is getting evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
StrToValue([MDXCode].[Code].CurrentMember.Name)
```

Edit upon further info. If you can make MDX Formula a property of Ratio Name:

```
StrToValue([Finance Ratio].[Ratio Name].CurrentMember.Properties("MDX Formula"))
```

Comment: @OverflowStack this situation sounds quite exotic - what is the use case for creating this structure?

Comment: It is Exotic! End users can create financial ratio's on GLAccounts f.e. GL Account number abc / GL Account number xyz = Ratio A. With a stored procedure this business formula gets translated to MDX in a field. Based on this field and the above code StrToValue() I can give the end user the ability to Compare multiple ratio's over time.

Comment: @GregGalloway I have still 1 problem. I need to add the [MDXCode].[Code] attribute to the query (Excel) or it does not work and I geet a #Value error..

Comment: @OverflowStack how do you want the query or pivot to look? Can you include a screenshot of the attribute relationships tab?

Comment: @GregGalloway Here it is shown http://postimg.org/image/56me6d4s3/     http://postimg.org/image/6003hoanx/  In the second screen you see clear the #value error if the MDX formula is not shown

Comment: And what attribute do you want users to add to their pivot?

Comment: That they just add "Ratio Name" on rows and the "Finance Ratio" on values and get the number. If the "MDX Formula" field is not in the pivot it don't work and get the error #VALUE

Comment: I saw the attribute relationships screenshot but can't get back to it now. Can you make MDX Formula related to Ratio Name? If so see my edit